# LINQ Performance: For vs. LINQ difference gone in C# 6?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

**Edit:** Per DavidG's suggestion, I boosted the number of items by 100x.  I reran the comparison in release mode and updated the results below.  I've also updated the code in case anyone is just copying and pasting and running it locally.

---

So I've seen a lot of posts on SO about LINQ vs. `for` performance -- most of which are several years old at this point -- and I wanted to see it in action for myself.  So I wrote a small app to test it, and the results were... not quite what I expected.  **My question is: have changes and optimizations in C# 6 made the entire performance issue irrelevant?**

(Inasmuch as it was ever an issue instead of an interesting micro-optimization for a large portion of the .NET user base.  Interesting, yes, but not something *most* people need to really worry about.)

I know there are still good questions about using manual loops vs. LINQ from a memory footprint standpoint, but either my comparison app is badly flawed or it doesn't seem like there's much of a speed difference anymore.  Perhaps it was optimized away in later versions of C#?

My sample app is below.  It's contrived, I admit -- it's a worst-case scenario trying to find an item that will be found dead last in a million-item list -- but I grabbed it based on other posts around here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            RunPerformanceComparison();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private void RunPerformanceComparison()
        {
            Func<string, bool> criteriaFunction = d => d.Equals("YES");

            var data = new string[100000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                data[i] = "NO";
            }

            data[data.Length - 1] = "YES";


            Console.WriteLine("With LINQ");
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            DoPerformanceRunLinq(data, criteriaFunction);

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Without LINQ");
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            DoPerformanceRunManual(data, criteriaFunction);
        }

        private void DoPerformanceRunLinq(string[] data, Func<string, bool> criteriaFunction)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                sw.Start();
                var result = data.Where(criteriaFunction).Select(d => d).ToList();
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i + 1}\tElapsed: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("n2")} ms");
                sw.Reset();
            }
        }

        private void DoPerformanceRunManual(string[] data, Func<string, bool> criteriaFunction)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                sw.Start();
                var result = GetItems(data, criteriaFunction);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i + 1}\tElapsed: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("n2")} ms");
                sw.Reset();
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetItems(string[] data, Func<string, bool> criteriaFunction)
        {
            var ret = new List<string>();

            // Not deferred; runs all at once
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (criteriaFunction(data[i]))
                {
                    ret.Add(data[i]);
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output from running this (I ran it in the command-line without VS):

```
With LINQ
------------
Iteration 1     Elapsed: 602.39 ms
Iteration 2     Elapsed: 522.72 ms
Iteration 3     Elapsed: 601.15 ms
Iteration 4     Elapsed: 518.71 ms
Iteration 5     Elapsed: 511.38 ms
Iteration 6     Elapsed: 565.92 ms
Iteration 7     Elapsed: 506.51 ms
Iteration 8     Elapsed: 524.91 ms
Iteration 9     Elapsed: 540.85 ms
Iteration 10    Elapsed: 502.33 ms

Without LINQ
------------
Iteration 1     Elapsed: 496.09 ms
Iteration 2     Elapsed: 496.15 ms
Iteration 3     Elapsed: 540.53 ms
Iteration 4     Elapsed: 549.28 ms
Iteration 5     Elapsed: 404.46 ms
Iteration 6     Elapsed: 407.23 ms
Iteration 7     Elapsed: 461.39 ms
Iteration 8     Elapsed: 414.90 ms
Iteration 9     Elapsed: 405.67 ms
Iteration 10    Elapsed: 437.98 ms
```

Over 100 *million* strings, that's better performance on the `for` side, but not by the significant amounts that some people have claimed in the past (I've heard as much as a 10x difference.  This is not even close.).  Plus, it's 100 million strings in memory -- I don't think the optimization here would be done by choosing manual loops vs LINQ. :)  In fact, I'm not sure the difference here is large enough for *anyone* to really care, unless you absolutely, positively need every last microsecond of performance.  I'd call it a wash, basically.

Did I screw up my app somewhere, is this just an invalid comparison, or did something change internally to .NET?

Comment: 6 milliseconds isn't enough iterations to get a good benchmark. Try it with 100 times more elements and you may start to see some differences. However, the difference has always been very small, not enough for most situations to worry about it.

Comment: Also make sure you run it in release mode...

Comment: As an aside, have a look at [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/).

Comment: @DavidG Good point.  I boosted it by 100x as you suggested and ran it in release, then updated the post.  At this point, that's 100 million strings -- frankly, if you have that much in memory you probably have bigger problems than LINK vs. `for`. :)

Comment: You're also measuring different things here, the two methods are not equivalent.

Comment: @DavidG That's part of what I'm trying to get at.  I'm missing the difference here.  How so?  They're both using the same criteria, filtering the list to items that match it, and generating a list of items that match.  I wouldn't be surprised that I'm missing something; I'm just struggling to figure out exactly what I'm missing. :)

Comment: Does the `ToList` method create the list in the same way by adding items one by one? I would doubt it. Also, you don't have 100 million strings in memory. String interning means you only have a single copy. This is why benchmarking is not always obvious.

Comment: Fair, though it's worth pointing out that this is extremely contrived -- if this were a real-world scenario you really *would* have 100 million strings out there.  As for `ToList()`, from what I can tell it really does add items to a return list one-by-one: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs  (Edit: Even if it's not 100 million strings in memory, it's still looking at a 100 million-item collection.)

Comment: You are basically testing `Where` perfomance, which is optimized for several special cases. For example if you pass array there (like you do) - it will iterate it with almost the same code as you do in "manual" branch. One match is best possible case for Where (by they way you are not trying to find item - you always iterate whole array). Also, `Select(d => d)` is useless so you can remove it for fairness (will speedup linq a bit more). `ToList` also doesn't affect anything since there is only one match.

Comment: @Evk Makes sense.  I'm looking for a better illustration of the perf differences in general, so if I'm dealing with an ideal `Where` case, what would you suggest doing instead?  Good point about the `Select`; forgot about that.  As for the `ToList()` it's only there because I discovered that, as written, the LINQ expression wouldn't even execute without `ToList()` there to "resolve" it.

Comment: If you want to observe bad perfomance in your situation, move select like this: `data.Select(c => c).Where(criteriaFunction).ToList();`. Should perform much worse.

Comment: @Evk Oh, I see.  Yeah, that's a better comparison, and I can think of a real-world application where someone would do that.  Thanks!

Comment: Changing the `"NO"` to be `$"NO{i}"` greatly increases the setup time, and increases the search time 50%, but reduces the difference between manual and LINQ from 18% slower to 6% slower.

Comment: Changing to use 10 random criteria functions that match a random single item, changes LINQ overhead to 8% slower. Using one that matches two random items reduces the LINQ overhead to 5%. I think there is not much overhead to LINQ and it decreases as criteria becomes more complex.

Comment: OTOH, embedding the criteria function in the manual version increases the LINQ overhead to 12%, and I think that is realistic use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you are measuring `Where` perfomance, in best possible conditions for it. It's optimized (has special handling) for some common cases. You are using it with array, and with arrays `Where` will iterate them with almost the same code you use in "manual" scenario. Since there is only one match, iterator `MoveNext` method will only be called once (well, maybe twice). Long story short - `Where` and manual loop in your conditions has similar perfomance because they run similar code.

If you want to observe (artificially) bad perfomance without much changes, try this:

```
data.Select(c => c).Where(criteriaFunction).ToList();
```

Now what you pass to `Where` is not array but "real" `IEnumerable` (returned by `Select`), and special handling for arrays do not apply. I ran your code with this modification and `Where` then performs 4 times slower than manual loop.

If that feels unfair and far from real usage, you can do it like this:

```
class DataItem {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// loop version
private IEnumerable<string> GetItems(DataItem[] data, Func<string, bool> criteriaFunction) {
    var ret = new List<string>();
    // Not deferred; runs all at once
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
        if (criteriaFunction(data[i].Value)) {
            ret.Add(data[i].Value);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

// linq version
var result = data.Select(c => c.Value).Where(criteriaFunction).ToList();
```

This is something that one can really do with LINQ, and it's about 4 times slower that loop version with your data. Of course LINQ version can be optimized, but point is - there are cases when LINQ might be significantly slower, especially if you are not careful.

There are many such examples. Consider this completely innocent LINQ `Count`:

```
var result = data.Count(c => c.Value == "YES");
```

And analog with `for`:

```
private int ForCount(DataItem[] data) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {                
        if (data[i].Value == "YES") {
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

LINQ is 3 times slower. And so on.

Comment: I don't think that is fair to LINQ since the "manual" version gets to perform with an array - put `Select().ToArray()` and see what happens.

Comment: Changing manual to take `IEnumerable` and use `foreach` and passing `data.Select(d=>d)`, LINQ is 12% slower than manual.

Comment: I've updated answer a bit, with a version that one actually might have used in real life, and which is slower, and clarified my point.

Comment: With your second example, I think you could also go ahead and embed (inline) the criteria method in the loop as LINQ requires a method but looping doesn't (just like you inlined the `Select`) and that would give LINQ much worse overhead. But what is the overhead for `Where(w => criteriaFunction(w.Value))` which seems like how I would use LINQ?

Comment: @NetMage I've added one more very simple example (one `Count` with condition), which is 3 times slower. Hope that will convince you.

Comment: It seems `Where().Select()` is (much) faster than `Select().Where()` due to the array optimizations (67% slower versus 19% slower) and similarly since `Count` has no array optimization, `Where().Count()` is faster than `Count(`pred`)` (12% slower versus 47% slower) but the main thing that puzzles me is why you are seeing 3x - 4x slowdowns versus looping and I am seeing <2x?

Comment: @NetMage Well, that I don't know. I just run OP code, without debugger, in release config, with minor modifications. Last version with Count is constantly 3x slower for me (~1100ms vs ~350ms). Note that I use array of `DataItem` instead of string array.

Comment: Checking more carefully, I was still using `Where().Count()` - with `Count(`pred`)` my timing are more like yours (3X). That just suggests to me LINQ could be improved for more special cases - an extension method on `Count<T>(this T[] a, Func<T,bool> test)` is as fast as a manual `for` loop without inlining the predicate method.